# Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in C:\xampp\htdocs\PAW Proyecto Alcoholes\funciones.php on line 67

Tags: php, session, warnings

Tengo de proyecto escolar y en este, tengo que realizar una pagina web, yo decidí hacerlo de un punto de venta de alcoholes, tengo un carrito y estoy utilizando un archivo de .php llamado funciones en el que tengo esta función

```
function iniciarSesionSiNoEstaIniciada()//Iniciar Sesion de Carrito
{
    if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
        session_start();
    }
    //$_SESSION['blabla'];
}
```

y me genera este error en la pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En realidad no me genera tanto problema, puedo agregar productos al carrito, pero lo que pasa es que detecta como multiples sesiones, y al agregar 2 productos iguales y deseo eliminarlos se borran los dos, y ademas ese mensaje de Warning que molesta.

Intente usar un:

```
session_start(); //al inicio con php y un 
include_once("funciones.php"); //que me manda al 
$_SESSION /*que se ve comentado, y funciona, pero me da otro tipo de error, que es el siguiente.*/
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe recalcar, que soy un novato en PHP, la primera funcion la saque de un foro en github, y la segunda manera de conectarme no estoy seguro si necesito hacer algo mas.
AYUDA, Se los agradecería mucho.
PD: se que el nombre de la carpeta esta mal por los espacios xd.

Comment: Por favor agrega imágenes únicamente cuando sea necesario. Edita tu post y cambia las imágenes por el código que tengas al momento.

Comment: @DavElsanto en este caso no están de mas la imágenes las imágenes son mal vidas cuando contienen el código que debe ser texto...

Comment: en cuanto al error: es correcto por algún motivo tienes algún `echo` el cual esta haciendo output antes de llegar al `session_start();` esto suele pasar incluso hasta por algun espacio al final del archivo php si tienes Cierres de etiquetas en tus archivos php.